# chromium process not show on Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system, chromium

I am working on Linux and learning Linux. I run the command on terminal

`sudo top`

but the chromium process not showing here. I just want to know Is chrome takes a large memory when it runs ? or chromium takes less from chrome memory. That's why I run the command to know both process memory usage and then analyze my own. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run `htop` instead?

Comment: Now I tried and its shows a better info